# How to access components of seasonal_decompose from statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I have two time series stored in data frames `london` and `scotland` of the same length and same columns. One column in `date` which spans from 2009 to 2019 and has a daily frequency for data of column `yearly_cost`. They look as such:

```
    Date        Yearly_cost
0   2009-01-01  230
1   2009-01-02  460
2   2009-01-03  260
3   2009-01-04  250
4   2009-01-05  320
5   2009-01-06  430
```

I wish to compare the euclidean distance of only the seasonality components of `yearly_cost` in the time series. I have decomposed them using `seasonal_decompose()` from statsmodels, however I wish to take only the seasonality component from the object:

`result = <statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.DecomposeResult at 0x2b5d7d2add8>`

Is this possible to take and create into a time series in a `new_df`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This was posted in my first month of coding. Perhaps better to delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked this out. To obtain the seasonal component, you simply use

`new_df = result.seasonal`

This gives you only the seasonal result.